# Articles in 'make time for'

Tags: articles, definite-article, time, zero-article

Does anyone know why the phrase 'make time for' uses a zero article for time? I know time is uncountable and most phrases about time use a zero article (spend time, save time, etc), however if the time is specific (you're wasting the time I gave you) it can have 'the.' So why in the phrase 'I'll make time for you at 7' is there no definite article?

Comment: In your example, the use of "time" is the same uncountable time - it is not referring to the specific time 7 o'clock. Just as when you say "I'll make time for you tomorrow".

Answer (score 1):

Time is still uncountable here. It's like saying you'll make room for something. To "**make time for**" someone or something is to free up time, to make oneself available. That doesn't change just because it's happening at a specific time.